# EchoServer, EchoClient in Android

Tags: android, echo-server

I am trying to implement a simple EchoServer, EchoClient application with 2 Android Devices.
But I have a major problem with the input methods in the Android.
In Java, the common System.in input method is used but in Android I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

In Android, System.in and System.out are not used. You can use Log.d("TAG", "MESSAGE") to print to the debug log.

A tutorial for creating a connection between phones is [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/), but if you haven't done any Android programming before, I suggest that you start by browsing through the [Dev Guide](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).